# Count Active Directory users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

The code below is supposed to count and compare user and output the total count, but somehow the result is empty. What do I need to do to fix it?

```
$groups = $A_group, $B_Group
$gm     = @()

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $gm += Get-ADGroupMember $group -Recursive |
           `where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} |`  
           ' select SamAccountName'
}

($gm.samaccountname | Select -Unique).Count
Write-Output total: ($gm.samaccountname | Select -Unique).Count
```

Comment: Your pipeline syntax is broken. Remove the backticks and single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a much more powershell-esque way.

```
$groups  = $A_group, $B_Group
$uniqueMemberCount = $groups |
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Where-Object {$_.objectClass -ieq "user"} |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    Measure-Object |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

Write-Output "Total: $uniqueMemberCount"
```

Comment: I got it. How do I export to CVS witch this Write-Output "Total: $uniqueMemberCount"?

Comment: Got it Work now!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count of the unique members of two groups:

```
$aGroup = @('a','b','c')
$bGroup = @('b','c','e','f')
(Compare-Object $aGroup $bGroup -IncludeEqual).count
```

Comment: That's right and also count the nested groups. There are hundreds of users so with the code you mentioned won't do.

Comment: Your question says nothing about counting nested groups.